# git create new branch from a specific branch history and commit

Tags: git, version-control

**I basically want to do:**

```
git checkout branchA
git checkout -b branchB <commit_id>
```

which creates the new `branchB` branch from `<commit_id>` on `branchA`.

**Question:**

I'm getting into details here but the reason I'm asking is to help understand how git history works and to save a bit of typing. (the command above could of been four commands instead of two...) How do I get it to one with native git functions? Question:

*Is there an easier/one line way of doing the same as above?*

I was thinking of simply doing `git checkout -b branchB <commit_id>` but if I'm in `branchC` that probably won't work cause the log/history of `branchC` might not be the same as `branchA`.

**Background:**

My intension for this specific situation would be to quickly revert to a previous commit in case a bug was introduced to production. I however still want to keep my new code and then discard of the new branch one the old code was pushed back to the server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just

```
git checkout -b branchB <commit>
```

The hash of the commit is unique within the whole repository, thus there is no reason to change to `branchA` before, because the result is completely the same.

Also this is just a shortcut for

```
git checkout <commit>
git branch branchB
git checkout branchB
```

As you can see the first command is a normal checkout, that will supersede your `git checkout branchA` anyway.

> I was thinking of simply doing `git checkout -b branchB <commit_id>` but if I'm in branchC that probably won't work cause the log/history of branchC might not be the same as branchA.

There is only one history in one repository.

> My intension for this specific situation would be to quickly revert to a previous commit in case a bug was introduced to production. I however still want to keep my new code and then discard of the new branch one the old code was pushed back to the server.

Sounds like [tags](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-tag) ;)

```
git tag -a -m "Release 1.2.3" v1.2.3
# Deploy 1.2.3
#something broken!
git checkout v1.2.2
# Deploy 1.2.2
```

Answer (score 2):

These commands

```
git checkout -b branchB <commit_id>
git checkout -b branchB branchA
```

mean *I want to create a branch X based on branch (or commit) Y*, thus you don't have to be in Y so that works.

The case were you would need to move to the base branch first is:

```
git checkout branchA
git checkout -b branchB
```

See that I didn't mention the base branch in the second line.

Also, remember that a commit is not specific to a branch, which is simply a pointer and nothing more. A branch can be deleted, move, renamed, etc. But the commits won't change.